# Jquery Validation on Form Submition

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to develop a validation script for a proyect using Jquery, the idea is to use the validation script for any form submitted so the form id will vary, also form elements and form actions or methods. hence I have writen the following script but it is failing to process step 2 when the 1st field pass the validation and it submits the form anyways.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    var form_Submited = $(this).attr("name");
    var form_Action = $(this).attr("action");
    var form_Information = $(this).serialize();
    var form_Elements = $(this)[0].elements;
    var i = 0;

    e.preventDefault();

    function Validation(){
        for (i; i < form_Elements.length; i++) {
            if (form_Elements[i].type === "text" && form_Elements[i].value === " " || form_Elements[i].value === null || form_Elements[i].value === 0 || form_Elements[i].value.length < 1) {
                console.log(form_Elements[i].name + ": " + form_Elements[i].value.length);
                return false;            
            }
            else if (form_Elements[i].type === "password" && form_Elements[i].value === " " || form_Elements[i].value === null || form_Elements[i].value === 0 || form_Elements[i].value.length < 1) {
                console.log(form_Elements[i].name + ": " + form_Elements[i].value.length);
                return false;            
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(Validation() === true){
            $.ajax({
                url: form_Action,
                data: form_Information,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (propName, val) {
                        $("#post-wrapper").append("<table><tr>");
                        $("#post-wrapper").append("<td>");
                        $("#post-wrapper").append(propName + ": " + val);
                        $("#post-wrapper").append("</td>");
                        $("#post-wrapper").append("</tr></table>");
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('Cannot retrieve data.');
                }
            });
    }   
});
```

Hope it is clear to understand it :(

Regards,

G.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking for `form_Elements[i].value === ""` instead of `form_Elements[i].value === " "` (notice the blank space) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because of your Validation() function. Inside your for loop, during the first iteration it checks the validity of the first field and if valid returns true. This is not correct, and that is why if the first field is valid the form submits. You should return true only after the for loop has completed

Also note that in your if and else if conditions you need to put the or (||) part in '(' ')'. && operator has more precedence than or (||)

Modified code (remove else condition and put return true outside for loop + parantheses added to if and else if conditions):

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
var form_Submited = $(this).attr("name");
var form_Action = $(this).attr("action");
var form_Information = $(this).serialize();
var form_Elements = $(this)[0].elements;
var i = 0;

e.preventDefault();


function Validation(){
    var valid = true;
    for (var i=0; i < form_Elements.length; i++) {
        if (form_Elements[i].type === "text" && (form_Elements[i].value === " " || form_Elements[i].value === null || form_Elements[i].value === 0 || form_Elements[i].value.length < 1)) {
            console.log(form_Elements[i].name + ": " + form_Elements[i].value.length);
            return false;          
        }
        else if (form_Elements[i].type === "password" && (form_Elements[i].value === " " || form_Elements[i].value === null || form_Elements[i].value === 0 || form_Elements[i].value.length < 1)) {
            console.log(form_Elements[i].name + ": " + form_Elements[i].value.length);
            return false;            
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if(Validation() === true){

    $.ajax({
            url: form_Action,
            data: form_Information,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (propName, val) {
                    $("#post-wrapper").append("<table><tr>");
                    $("#post-wrapper").append("<td>");
                    $("#post-wrapper").append(propName + ": " + val);
                    $("#post-wrapper").append("</td>");
                    $("#post-wrapper").append("</tr></table>");
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Cannot retrieve data.');
            }
        });


}

});
```

Comment: @GuillermoFernandez Please do accept the answer if you are satisfied by clicking on the tick mark below it :)